# How do I add formatting in a link in Perl Pod?

Tags: perl, hyperlink, perl-pod

I wonder: I have some POD with `=item`s like this:

```
=item B<some-option=>I<some_value>
```

When I try to create a link in the text, none of those works:

```
L<B<some-option=>I<some_value>>, L<some-option=some_value>
```

Using `pod2html` I see that there are `name=` for the `=item`s, but the `L<..>` command just produces `<em>...</em>` output.

How can I create a proper link for the `=item`?

Here's a short sample POD:

```
=pod

See L<B<--some-option=>I<some_value>> or L<--some-option=some_value>.

=over

=item B<--some-option=>I<some_value>

Blabla...

=back
```

Also `podchecker --warnings --warnings --warnings` says `pod syntax OK.`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To nest formatting codes, the outer one needs an extra set of angle brackets and some white space.  The white space is ignored in the output.

```
L<< /B<some-option=>I<some_value> >>
```

This is documented in the [Formatting Codes section of perlpod](https://metacpan.org/pod/perlpod#Formatting-Codes) after the list of codes.

Comment: Actually this does not solve the problem: `pod2html` now reports `Cannot find "--some-option=some_value" in podpath: cannot find suitable replacement path, cannot resolve link`, and the HTML generated essentially is `<p>See <a><b>--some-option=</b><i>some_value</i></a> or <a>--some-option=some_value</a>.</p>`.

Comment: You didn't include the /

Comment: I re-read the perlpod manual page, but couldn't find a reference to `/`; is it that slash of `/"sec"`?

Comment: I improved your answer to be more direct and obvious -- sorry!

Comment: Yes, slash is to indicate that you are linking to a section of a pod document.  In this case, the current document.  The error you got about searching podpath means it is searching for a pod file, not a section.  So I expect that means you didn't include the / in your link.